# Can someone help me with this limit?

Tags: limits, infinitesimals

$ \lim_{x \to 0}x^{|\tan x |} \overset{??}{=} 1 ??$

If you consult the graph it is intuitive to think that when $ x \to 0 $ the function tends to $1$. I have tried to lower the exponent with logarithms and apply L'Hospital's rule, but nothing. The only solution I see is to apply infinitesimal equivalents, which I have not tried yet.

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you have a result that the limit is $1$ with $|x|$ the exponent?  $|\tan x|$ is very close to that.

Comment: $ \lim_{x \to 0} x^{|x|} = 1 $, it is trivial. I have been guaranteed that the limit exists, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}x^{|\tan x |} \overset{??}{=} 1 ??$$
Take log
$$\ln L =\lim_{x \to 0}  {\ln x} \,{\tan x}$$
$$\ln L =\lim_{x \to 0} {\ln (1-(x+1))}\, {\tan x}$$
$$\ln L =\lim_{x \to 0}  {-(x+1)} \,{ x}$$
$$\ln L= 0 \implies L=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Determine the limit of the logarithm, using that $\tan x\sim_0 x$.

Comment: It may be a good choice. But would it be correct to show it this way? I'm not used to showing limits with infiniteism.

Comment: Well, you should learn to do it. L'Hospital's rule is not the alpha and omega of limits computation.

Comment: @Bernard. *Bravo, bravissimo !!* and cheers :-)